# Why does nunit not run a test which contains control/special chars

Tags: c#, special-characters, nunit-3.0

If I have a test class like

```cs
public class Tests
{
    [TestCaseSource(nameof(TestSource))]
    public void Test(string c)
    {
        Assert.Pass();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<object> TestSource()
    {
        for (char c = '\0'; c < 255; c++)
        {
            yield return c.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

then the test runner in the Visual Studio can discover all the tests but doesn't run all of them.

these are the ascii character ranges that are not running:

```
U_0001 - U_0006
U_000E - U_001F
U_007F - U_0084
U_0086 - U_009F
```

We currently use some of these characters like `U_0002` for network work related test which are included in the test but currently do not run

This is the output for the test run

```
---------- Starting test discovery for requested test run ----------
NUnit Adapter 3.17.0.0: Test discovery starting
NUnit Adapter 3.17.0.0: Test discovery complete
========== Test discovery finished: 255 Tests found in 4,8 sec ==========
---------- Starting test run ----------
NUnit Adapter 3.17.0.0: Test execution started
Running selected tests in C:\Users\WEIK014\source\repos\TestSourceTestProject\TestSourceTestProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\TestSourceTestProject.dll
   NUnit3TestExecutor discovered 199 of 199 NUnit test cases
NUnit Adapter 3.17.0.0: Test execution complete
========== Test run finished: 199 Tests run in 8,6 sec (199 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped) ==========
```

as you see it doesn't even recognize that it skips tests.

Versions in the project:

- Project .Net Core 2.1
- NUnit 3.13.1
- NUnit3TestAdapter 3.17.0

Here is some visual proof that these test do not run
[image]

Comment: Did you try to run the tests outside VS and test adapter, just using console?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski not jet. So far I didn't found the time. I will add infos for that later.

Comment: I've found just the similar (or even the same) [issue #484](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/484), it seems that you should update your `.runsettings` file, at least with [`UseNUnitIdforTestCaseId`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/vs-test-adapter/Tips-And-Tricks.html#usenunitidfortestcaseid) value

Comment: Pavel's right - although I believe you'll need the `UseParentFQNForParametrizedTests` setting too. The cause of this bug is that the different NUnit layers communicate in XML, and these test names can't be accurately encoded in XML - a fix is in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that sounds like it's probably a bug somewhere in Visual Studio or the test adapter with displaying Unicode control characters. As a workaround, you can override the test display name for control characters:

```
public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> TestSource()
{
    for (char c = '\0'; c < 255; c++)
    {
        var data = new TestCaseData(c.ToString());
        if (char.IsControl(c))
        {
            data.SetArgDisplayNames($"{(int)c:X4}");
        }
        yield return data;
    }
}
```

This will preserve the display for printable characters (e.g. `Test("a")`), and the control characters will display as `Test(0001)`, etc.